# Configuring the Seq URL from a single place

Tags: c#, .net, serilog, seq

I have a solution with a bunch of .net framework applications that are all configured to use Seq for logging. Currently I have the same settings duplicated in every app.config file:

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" />
        <add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://localhost:5341" />
</appSettings>
```

If I would like to be able to configure the Seq URL for all the applications from a single file, not only when running in Visual Studio but also when the system has been deployed.

How can this be done?

I have looked into creating a common settings file and include it in all applications using `<appSettings file="CommonSettings.config">`, but from what I understand this actually creates a copy of the file for each application.